# How to implement over() in hiveql

Tags: hive, hiveql

> As I am new to hive I am trying to implement some function of sql in
>   hive.How to implement over() function of sql in hive.
>   I am using shark 0.8.0 which uses hive 0.9 where in this version over() is not implemented.

Comment: Windowing function require special operators. You cannot implement them as a 'function'. I recommend read https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-896

Answer (score 0):

you can see a full description of the syntax [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics)

Comment: I am using shark 0.8.0 which uses hive 0.9 and over() function is not available in it.How can I implement it.

Comment: what analytic function do you want to implement using "over()"?